# C#+Selenium web scraping

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scrape some data from https://zakup.sk.kz.

First, I initialize my browser:

```
IWebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
        browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://zakup.sk.kz/#/ext?tabs=lot&adst=PUBLISHED&lst=PUBLISHED&page=1");
```

After, I click to the frame:

```
IWebElement click = browser.FindElement(By.ClassName("m-found-item__num"));
        click.Click();
```

In this frame exist data that I want to scrape (I found abs path):

```
IWebElement tru = browser.FindElement(By.XPath("/html[1]/body[1]/ngb-modal-window[1]/div[1]/div[1]/sk-main-dialog[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[7]"));
        Console.WriteLine(tru.Text);
```

After this, I need to switch to the next frame with the same structure, and scrape data:

```
IWebElement next = browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'm-modal__arrow')]"));
        next.Click();
IWebElement tru2 = browser.FindElement(By.XPath("/html[1]/body[1]/ngb-modal-window[1]/div[1]/div[1]/sk-main-dialog[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[7]"));
        Console.WriteLine(tru2.Text);
```

But Selenium not found tru2, I don't know why, because every frame has the same structure? Tell me please, what should I do?

Comment: What are the _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: I want to train scrap data with Selenium, after this I will think about automation.

Comment: My task is to scrap data from this site: zakup.sk.kz. There are about 10 frames in one page, each fram has this data, I found data from the first frame, but the code to the second frame doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you click the `next` arrow the current element will be deleted and added after Ajax request finished, here you need `WebDriverWait`

```
IWebElement next = browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'm-modal__arrow')]"));
        next.Click();

// wait max 15 seconds
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))
IWebElement tru2 = wait.Until(browser => browser.FindElement(By.XPath("(//div[@class="m-infoblock__layout"])[7]")));
        Console.WriteLine(tru2.Text);
```

note that I use Xpath

```
(//div[@class="m-infoblock__layout"])[7]
```

Comment: Thank you, mister! But this Iwait wait not works, I used browser.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);